# p4 is stuck when submitting

Tags: perforce, p4v

I was trying to submit the Unreal Engine (250k files) to the depot via `p4v`, however, one day passed and it seemed like the submit was still doing some operations or was hung. To get more verbosity, I then used the `p4 submit -c #number` to commit via cli and I've realized that it got stuck on a pdb file.

```
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0/12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0/12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core/14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core/14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0/12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0/12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v12.0.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build/12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build/12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build/14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build/14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.Build/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Build.pdb#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.CSharp/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.dll#1
add //test/test/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.CSharp/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.CSharp.pdb#1
```

Is there anything that is odd? How would I debug this?

Comment: This is just a guess, but try NTHandle to see if anything on the client machine is blocking access to that file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle  I have some dim memory of Visual Studio holding some kind of weird lock on PDB files that causes reads to hang instead of fail.  I'd typically just exclude .PDBs from my client view to avoid problems like this since they're generated.

Comment: I've tried looking for locks with `ProcessExplorer` (should be similar to handle) and the only process having a handle was `p4.exe` Rerunning the command it always seems to be a different file.

Comment: Interestingly, when I use `-parallel` on the submit command it seems to make more progress in adding files but then again comes to a point where it's stuck.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has anyone figured out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question to this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77118625/3854396

This is probably due to unreliable network stability, so the solution is to allow retries with a network timeout for files that get stuck.