# Perforce has a scalability issue with large number of files to submit, reconcile, or integrate. Anything I can do to speed it up?

Tags: perforce

I'm working with the unreal engine so when Epic does an update to the engine, there can be a need to update 100k files or more. The perforce server sits in an AWS instance.
The normal way to manage unreal engine updates, even recommended by perforce, is to write over the local files and use 'reconcile' to find the changes.
The reconcile on my laptop which was cutting edge maybe 3 years ago takes 12 hours and then fails silently.
If I manage to make the proper changelist, by adding things little by little, and I hit submit, it takes 12 hours and fails silently.
Doing a submit in p4v will "jam" perforce (the process will stall indefinitely and when killed no other perforce command will complete, even trivial ones). The only way to get perforce commands working again is to reboot the client computer.
When using the command line interface, commands like reconcile or submit have no useful output as to what is going on and return error messages such as:

```
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 1996'
```

Anything I can do to speed these things up or figure out what is perforce choking on?

Comment: You don't mention which client you're using, but the truncated error message makes me think you're using P4V -- if that's the case, try running the same commands from the CLI, and you should get more useful information.  (You might also be able to find the output in P4V's "log" pane, although I've always had mixed luck there.)

Comment: On another avenue of investigation: have you looked at the log on the server?  If the server is "jammed" when you're opening only 100k files it suggests that it's under-resourced; there might be more useful information in the log, but regardless I'd start by increasing the amount of memory available to it.

Comment: @Samwise I tried from P4V and typing commands on windows cmd shell. Neither gave me more details than the other. Not sure how to find the logs on the server. I didn't set the server up. Is there a remote way to get those?

Comment: Talk to the person who set the server up.  You can get the logs remotely using `p4 logparse` and/or `p4 logtail` but you need superuser permissions, and if you're not the admin you probably don't have those permissions (or shouldn't).  In any case, fixing the server is going to require reconfiguring the AWS instance so that it can handle the load for your project; you won't be able to do it by running client commands.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the failing submit, repeat it from the command line.  The command line client will show you output for each file in the changelist, along with an error message for any where the transfer failed:

```
C:\Perforce\test\submit>p4 submit -d "Test submit"
Submitting change 312.
Locking 2 files ...
add //stream/main/submit/bar#1
add //stream/main/submit/foo#1
open for read: c:\Perforce\test\submit\foo: The system cannot find the file specified.
Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 312'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
```

In the above example, note that the system error message (`The system cannot find the file specified.`) is printed on the line immediately before Perforce's `Submit aborted` error.  P4V will sometimes obscure this error by displaying it in a different place from the top-level error message, or not displaying it at all, but from the CLI you should always be able to find it by scrolling up in the terminal.

If the server is "jammed" when trying to open or submit 100k files, it suggests that it's under-resourced; Perforce installations scale to millions of files easily, but the hardware needs to be available to support that.  [Memory is the most typical bottleneck](https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/2957) so the first thing I'd check/adjust would be the memory allocation for your AWS instance.

Comment: The output in the OP is what I got from using the command line client and as you can see it's quite unhelpful: "Some file(s) could not be transferred from client". The previous submit messages all went through without a problem (or no problems reported in the output).  
The server has 8GB of ram allocated which seems like it would be enough.

Comment: To clarify something, when the submit "jams" (stops working and no subsequent perforce command completes at all, even trivial ones), the only way to get perforce working again is to reboot the client windows PC. Completely killing p4v and any perforce processes in the task manager is not enough for some reason.

Comment: Sounds worth contacting support for.  Something atypical is happening on your client machine and it’s going to take some back-and-forth to figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely from unreliable network conditions. The following is taken from the p4 documentation but worked for me in similar circumstances:

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v19.2/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/performance.diagnosing.network.html

I found I had to add the maxwait to my p4vcofig file instead of the command line.

> A safer approach If you are adding a large number of files over an unreliable connection, consider a file by file approach:
>
> `$ find directoryname -type f -exec p4 -r5 -vnet.maxwait=60 add {} \;`
> This finds all the files (-type f) in directoryname, and adds each one
> by invoking "`p4 -r5 -vnet.maxwait=60 add`" for each file individually.
>
> After all files have been added, assign the changelist a changelist
> number with p4 change, and submit the numbered changelist atomically
> with
>
> `$ p4 -r5 -vnet.maxwait=60 submit -c changenum` If connectivity is
> interrupted, the -r value causes the submission to resume.